# How to show x-axis labels in BubbleChart?

Tags: android, charts, bar-chart, mpandroidchart, bubble-chart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) BubbleChart v3.0.2. In this version I am unable to set my custom labels on xAxis. how can I set xAxis label for each bar. i.e (label1, label2 etc)

if any one worked in it or know how to do kindly share.

Comment: like we set granularity of chart. I want to set text label there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by extending `IValueFormatter`. If you wanted to create a simple mapping of `Entry` to `String` labels you could do it like this:

```
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ViewPortHandler;

import java.util.Map;

public class MapValueFormatter implements IValueFormatter {

    private final Map<Entry, String> labels;

    public MapValueFormatter(Map<Entry, String> labels) {
        this.labels = labels;
    }

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        String label = labels.get(entry);
        if (label == null) {
            return "";
        }

        return label;
    }
}
```

Then you can create labels like this:

```
Map<Entry,String> labels = new HashMap<>();
for (BubbleEntry bubbleEntry : dataSet.getValues()) {
    labels.put(bubbleEntry, generateRandomString());
}
dataSet.setValueFormatter(new MapValueFormatter(labels));
```

The result looks like this:

[image: a bubble chart with custom labels]

I am sure you can do better though. Good luck!

Comment: one more question. how can I show text in bubbles (text+y-axis value)?

Comment: @Mubashar can you please accept the answer if it is helpful? (green tick next to answer)

Comment: accepted because it worked and I didn't find this solution anywhere before.

Comment: @Mubashar thanks for the accept. To show (text + y-axis value) just change the code to: `return label + value;`

Comment: can you send any helpful link? I have problems. when I hardcode entries it work fine. but when I get from an arrayList and add in bar entry. it doesn't appear properly and not aligned to x-axis labels.

Comment: @Mubashar Please look at the code for the sample project. It's in the GitHub repo for MPAndroidChart. If you still have doubts and are getting stuck, then create a question containing a [mcve] that we can easily copy paste into an IDE and debug.